# Check All Array Without foreach Statement

Tags: php

How to check if there's no page information found in the database? If I were using `foreach` to check whether the page is exist or not, I will return false like the example below:

My router file:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=project1', 'root', '');
$GetDirectory = $db->prepare('
    SELECT *
    FROM pages
');
$GetDirectory->execute();
$GetDirectory = $GetDirectory->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (Route::Request_URL()=='/') {
    Route::Navigate_URL('home');
} else {
    foreach ($GetDirectory as $Directory) {
        switch (Route::Request_URL()) {
            case strpos(Route::Request_URL(), $Directory['request']) :
                if (Route::Verify_URL($Directory['pos1'], $Directory['pos2'], $Directory['request'])!==false) {
                    Route::Navigate_URL($Directory['name']);
                    $db = null;
                } else {
                    //this will give an error for each time it didn't found
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My class file:

```
class Route {
    public static function Request_URL() {
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    public static function Verify_URL($pos1, $pos2, $url) {
        if (strpos(substr(Route::Request_URL(), $pos1, $pos2), $url)!==false) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static function Navigate_URL($RequestURL) {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=project1', 'root', '');
        $ListDirectory = $db->prepare('
            SELECT *
            FROM pages
        ');
        $ListDirectory->execute();
        $ListDirectory = $ListDirectory->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($ListDirectory as $Directory) {
            switch ($RequestURL) {
                case $Directory['name'] :
                    return require_once SERVE_PATH.$Directory['path'];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long code. Wanna ask a simpler question, but don't know how to explain.

Comment: Maybe you could add a **WHERE clause** (_WHERE name='$pageid'_)  to your SQL statement. If found the data would be returned. Otherwise the foreach loop would not be perfomed at all.

Comment: well, this is the reason i do this code. checks if the url is the same with the one from mysql, so i **do** need `SELECT *`

Comment: You probably should use if statements instead of switch (for one "case" it does the same but is harder to read). And then can you tell us what the problem is? What is the expected result? What happens instead? Are there any error messages? If so, what do they say?